# C# DateTime.ParseExact throwing format exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.0

I'm developing an .NET4 webapplication using MVC3.

Let's say i'm getting the following DateTime as string from an XML-feed. The xml feed is being read by my application and i'm looping through all it's descendants. The DateTime i'm receiving is begin returned in the following format (as string);

```
var myDateTime = "Sun Dec 19 11:45:45 +0000 2010"
```

I'm using the piece of code below to try and parse the DateTime string i mentioned above to a valid DateTime format (preferably dutch)

```
var CorrectDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(myDateTime , "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

When trying to execute this code i'm facing an formatexception. Somebody has got any ideas?

--UPDATE--

This is what i've got after various answers. Still throwing the same exception though.

```
var correctedDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(latestTweetTime, "ddd MMM HH:mm:ss K yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string display = correctedDateTime.ToString("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: The format string is the format you're reading in, not the format you're writing to - see Andrew's answer.

Comment: @Jackson, thanks. Never knew that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to read this:
"Sun Dec 19 11:45:45 +0000 2010"

You need an additional "d" or "dd" like so:

```
"ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss K yyyy"
```

or

```
"ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss K yyyy"
```

depending on whether the input zero-prefixed.

You need each piece of the input string to be accounted for, here is a summary of the different components from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

```
ddd = Three letter Day of week
MMM = Three letter month
dd = Two digit day of month 01-31  (use "d" for 1-31)
HH = Hours using 24-hour clock. 00-24  (use "H" for 0-24)
mm = Minutes. 00-59
ss = Seconds. 00-59
K = Time zone information
yyyy = 4-digit year
```

Comment: To add, the steps are: 1) Convert a string to a DateTime  2) Convert the DateTime to something readable. The formatting page I linked to will be useful for both.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick! +1 For good answer, explaination and information

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your parsing format to this:

```
"ddd MMM HH:mm:ss K yyyy"
```

If you wish to *reformat* the `DateTime`then specify that format string when you call `DateTime.ToString` on your parsed `DateTime`:

```
string display = CorrectedDateTime.ToString("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: thanks for the clear answer! Though it keeps throwing me the same exception. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

According to the date you've specified (assuming the time is in 24 hour) your input format string should be:

```
ddd MMM d H:mm:ss K yyyy. 
Sun Dec 19 11:45:45 +0000 2010
```

So:

```
var correctedDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(myDateTime, "ddd MMM d H:mm:ss K yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string display = correctedDateTime.ToString("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

A couple of things to note, the extra single d to capture the date and I would use a single H to allow for '01' and '1'.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=VS.100).aspx for the full format details.